# Error defining parameters mysql string

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this peace of code where I need to retrieve data from `Mysql`. If I use parameterized query it does not take actual parameter value instead it takes parameter name as value.

> Error: @choise must be defined

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("");
MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;
DataSet DS;
private string columnValue = "xxx";
private string Choise = "yyy";
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE " + columnValue + " = @choise";
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@choise", Choise));
DS = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, connection);
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
connection.Close();
```

when I run this i get query like:

`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE xxx = @choise`

instead of

`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE xxx = yyy`.
Where is the problem?

I have tried:
`command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@choise", Choise));` 
and
`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@choise", Choise);`

It works fine when I'm using actual variables instead of parameters.

EDITED:

I get `columnvalue` and `Choise` from:

```
columnValue = "`"+DS.Tables[0].Columns[cmb1FilterColumns.SelectedIndex].ToString()+"`";
Choise = "'"+cmb1FilterValues.SelectedItem.ToString()+"'";
```

Comment: What are the values of `xxx` and `yyy` exactly? Are they another local variables or you just missed typed as `"xxx"` and `"yyy"`? And also what is `Choise` exactly?

Comment: missed typed "xxx" and "yyy", Just Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you edit your question, I think I find what is wrong.

You put your `columnValue` and `Choise` unnecessary single quotes. You don't need them.

Just use them like;

```
columnValue = DS.Tables[0].Columns[cmb1FilterColumns.SelectedIndex].ToString();
Choise = cmb1FilterValues.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Because with single quotes, your command will be like;

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE 'xxx' = 'yyy'
```

which seems not a valid sql.

Comment: if i do not put these single quotes i get fatal error which says wrong mysql statement.

Comment: Not sure how and why but earlier it was without quotes and throw me error now i removed it and it works... magic

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("");
MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;
DataSet DS;
private string columnValue = "xxx";
private string Choise =" yyy";
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE " + columnValue + " = @choise";
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@choise", Choise));
DS = new DataSet();
connection.Open();

dAdt.Fill(dSet)
mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter;
mySqlDataAdapter .SelectCommand = command;
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
connection.Close();
```

Comment: COME ONE, PROBLEM IS WHEN YOU BUILD STRING IT CANNOT TAKE PARAMETER VALUE INSTEAD IT TAKES PARAMETER NAME AS VALUE

Comment: string should be 
`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE xxx = yyy`
but it generates
`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE xxx = @choise`

Comment: commandtext is: SELECT * FROM participantinfo WHERE xxx = @choise

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
columnValue = DS.Tables[0].Columns[cmb1FilterColumns.SelectedIndex].ToString();
Choise = cmb1FilterValues.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

It seems unclear value for value `columnValue` and `Choise`..If it is string mention in double quotes

```
private string columnValue ="xxx";
private string Choise = "yyy";
```

---

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("");
MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;
DataSet DS;
private string columnValue ="xxx";
private string Choise ="yyy";
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE " + columnValue + " = @choise";
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@choise", Choise));
DS = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, connection);
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Maybe `xxx` and `yyy` are another local variables? `:)` For example; `xxx = "xxx"` and `yyy = "yyy"`

Comment: @SonerGönül yeah you are correct..But here i didnot see 'xxx = "xxx" and yyy = "yyy"'....That's why wrote like this

Comment: no this is just some random values i'm using text box to set values of these variables I have tried public, private string and simple string none worked....

Answer (score 0):

For some version of ADO.NET MYSQL connector the `@` sign doesn't work as expected. Try using `?` sign instead like

```
new MySqlParameter("?choise", choise);
```

Comment: I have tried @choise, ?choise, and choise. None of them helped